# Вычисление стоимости поездки такси. Java

Tags: java

Есть класс Taxi, нужно написать метод для вычисления стоимости поездки за расстоянием:
Минимальная цена поездки 40рублей

Первые 2км бесплатно
Каждый след. километр стоит 20р.

Comment: А в чем проблема?  Вы вроде не первый раз задаете вопрос, наверняка знаете что на SO нужно задавать вопросы по коду, а не выкладывать задания.

Comment: Нужно так нужно, пишите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сумма меньше `40р`, то вернет `null`

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Проверка
        System.out.println(getCost(1));
        System.out.println(getCost(21));
        System.out.println(getCost(40));
    }
    
    // Нужный метод
    private static Integer getCost(int km) {
        return km < 22 ? null:(km-20)*20;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!